# jQuery Regular Expression Returns Unexpected Results

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use the following code with jQuery to validate hex value strings but I get unexpected results:

```
var a = new RegExp("0x[a-fA-F0-9]+")
var result = a.test('0x1n')
```

In this case, result actually returns true. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need anchors to match the beginning and the end of the string. This will make the regular expression try to match against the *entire* string instead of just a part of the string:

```
var a = new RegExp("^0x[a-fA-F0-9]+$")
```

Otherwise your regular expression matches the `0x1` part and returns `true`.

On another note, the following would be a little better:

```
var re = /^0x[a-f0-9]+$/i;
```

The `i` flag makes it case insensitive so you don't have to specify `a-f` and `A-F`.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex does match that string, because you don't have any anchors on it. If you change your regex to `^0x[a-fA-F0-9]+$`, then the string `0x1n` will not match.

**Edit:** To further explain why your string matches, your regular expression is actually trying to match a string that contains `0x` followed by one or more characters in the `[a-fA-F0-9]` character class. The string `0x1n` contains `0x` followed by `1`, which is in the `[a-fA-F0-9]` character class.

Adding anchors means that your string must start with `0x`, then finish with one or more characters in the `[a-fA-F0-9]` character class. `0x1n` would fail to match, since it ends in an `n`, which is not in that character class.

Comment: Delimiters? Do you mean anchors? :)

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about... :-)

Answer (score 1):

It returns true because you're not requiring the entire string to match that pattern. Try this:

```
var a = new RegExp("^0x[a-fA-F0-9]+$")
```