# Regex expression not working on Google Form

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-forms, google-forms-api

I'm trying to use a TextValidationBuilder to validate input on a Google Form. I'm doing some tests and I have no idea why the regex isn't working. When I test the regex [here](https://regex101.com/) it works fine.

I want to use regex to validate that an input is a time or a number and I am doing this by checking if the format is something like "12:30PM" or "8:00AM" or "7."

Here is the regex: `([01]{0,1}\d:[0-6]\d((PM)|(AM)))|(\d+)`

I'm putting the expression manually into the form to test. (I know programmatically I'll need to write `\\d` and whatnot.

The regex doesn't seem to work and allows the following:

- "12:30" without the "AM" or "PM"
- "1234:5678"

However, when I just try to validate for the time, it works correctly. Using `[01]{0,1}\d:[0-6]\d((PM)|(AM)).` It only fails when I add the `or` case for digits only: `\d+`.

If anyone could help me that would be super appreciated! Thank you!!

[image]

Edit: I'm just doing some troubleshooting and here are some things I noticed that are a bit odd:

When I match for the time or a random number like:

`([01]{0,1}\d:[0-6]\d((PM)|(AM)))|1`,

it works and doesn't accept responses like "12:30." But when I match for the time or multiple numbers like:

`([01]{0,1}\d:[0-6]\d((PM)|(AM)))|[01]`,

it doesn't work and accepts "12:30."

Comment: `putting the expression manually into the form to test` Add screenshot please or describe it fully: What type of answer, what type of expression, whether you're using a fullmatch or just contains - need details to reproduce.

Comment: Thanks, just added a screenshot! Using a full match

Comment: *The regex doesn't seem to work and allows the following:   "12:30" without the "AM" or "PM"    "1234:5678"* No repro with your screenshot settings.

Comment: Your issue is that you have no anchors on the string, so your `(\d+)` alternation is free to match *anywhere* in the input, allowing `12:30` to be a match since `\d+` matches both `12` and `30`. Try [`^(([01]?\d:[0-5]\d([AP]M))|(\d+))$`](https://regex101.com/r/z4k6ci/3). Note `{0,1}` can be replaced with `?` and `[0-6]` should be `[0-5]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery Regular Expression Returns Unexpected Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814555/jquery-regular-expression-returns-unexpected-results)

Comment: @Nick AFAIK and  during actual testing, `matches` act equivalent to python's  ``re.fullmatch``. So, unless OP used `contains` for the regex,  I don't know how this solved OP's problem at all(Screenshot show OP using `matches`).

Comment: @TheMaster agreed, but the lack of anchors is the only thing which can explain the behaviour OP is seeing (and indeed adding them seems to have resolved the issue). So maybe the screenshot was a different test? I don't know... I'd certainly be interested if you can come up with another explanation

Comment: @Nick I briefly considered browser differences(as I wasn't able to repro). But, OP providing incorrect screenshot seems more probable.

Comment: Just double checked and yeah what's in the screenshot doesn't work for me but when I add anchors it does

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Nick in the comments, using anchors fixed my problem. Start the regex with ^ and end with $.